# How was memory allocated in Windows 9x compared to Windows 10 ?

Tags: windows, memory

I heard rumours that when a new program is executed in Windows 9x, that app had to specify how much memory it needs to allocate beforehand. How is this different in Windows 10 ?

Comment: Think about this for more than just 5 seconds. If your supposed rumor was true then how would programs like Photoshop (first in 1990) exist back then? Or even MS Word?

Comment: To be able to discuss on "rumors", you need to cite one or more places from which the rumor (or variations of it) were spread. Also, most discussions on "rumors" are off-topic here, as their invalidity is obvious to software programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Only the size of the main threads stack is hard-coded in the executable. (There's a parameter specifying it when creating new threads.)

That's the only thing which can be influenced, `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` for more than 2G address-space and [address-space-layout-randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) were later things.